# If I resize my canvas, my createJS text becames blurry

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs, createjs

I'm using createJS to drawn inside the canvas. I have my canvas set to occupy the browser window maintaining aspect ratio using the resize() function.

This is the code:

```
    mytext = new createjs.Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 2","19px Calibri","#073949");
    mytext.x = 450
    mytext.y = 300;
    stage.addChild(mytext);  

    resize = function() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var canvasRatio = canvas.height / canvas.width;

                var windowRatio = window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth;
                var width;
                var height;

                if (windowRatio < canvasRatio) {
                    height = window.innerHeight - 35;
                    width = height / canvasRatio;
                } else {
                    width = window.innerWidth;
                    height = width * canvasRatio;
                }

                canvas.style.width = width + 'px';
                canvas.style.height = height + 'px';    
    }()
```

What happens is that the text gets blurry (decrease of quality) when the canvas resizes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt43q.png
vs
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcGLO.png

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you store the size of the original canvas `width` and `height` then depending on the resize calculate the new scales then redraw all elements correctly by the new width and height? For example. original Width = 400 original height = 400, after resize width is now 800 and height is now 600. Run the draw function like so. `mytext.x = 400 * (canvas.width / originalWidth); then do the same for height and font size

Comment: I was trying to avoid that solution because I already built lots of games with tons of text and images and I would need to build a resize function for each game and also make up for the change of coordinates. But if that's the only solution I will have to apply it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using CreateJS, you can simply resize the canvas, and scale the entire stage to redraw everything at the new size:

```
// just showing width to simplify the example:
var newWidth = 800;
var scale = newWidth/myCanvas.width;
myCanvas.width = newWidth;
myStage.scaleX = myStage.scaleY = scale;
myStage.update(); // draw at the new size.
```

Answer (score 3):

@Adam's answer is correct as far as scaling the canvas goes. You do **NOT** want to scale with CSS, as it will stretch your canvas instead of changing its pixel dimensions. Set the width and height of the canvas using JavaScript instead.

```
stage.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
stage.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

As you stated in your comment, this will only change the canvas size, and not reposition or scale your content. You will have to do this manually. This is fairly simple. Generally, I recommend putting your "resize" listener in the JavaScript in your HTML file, rather than on a frame script.

---

First, determine the scale, based on the size of the window and the size of your content. You can use the `exportRoot.nominalBounds.width` and `exportRoot.nominalBounds.height` which is the bounds of the first frame. If you want to scale something else, use its `nominalBounds` instead.

*Note that nominalBounds is appended to all MovieClips exported from Flash/Animate. If you enable multi-frame bounds, and want to use those, you will have to modify your approach.*

The main idea is to use the original, unscaled size of your contents.

```
var bounds = exportRoot.nominalBounds;
// Uses the larger of the width or height. This will "fill" the viewport.
// Change to Math.min to "fit" instead.
var scale = Math.max(window.innerWidth / bounds.width, window.innerHeight / bounds.height);
exportRoot.scaleX = exportRoot.scaleY = scale;
```

You can then center it if you want.

```
exportRoot.x = *window.innerWidth - bounds.width*scale)/2;
exportRoot.y = *window.innerHeight - bounds.height*scale)/2;
```

Here is a quick sample of a responsive canvas using a simple shape as the scaling contents: 
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/4yy08pax/

Doing this with Flash/Animate CC export has come up a few times, so it is on my list of future EaselJS demos to include on [createjs.com](http://createjs.com), and in the [EaselJS GitHub](http://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've used your exportRoot approach but it only scales the objects that were placed on the screen in the Flash CC, all the objects I add with stage.addChild() doesn't scale.

Comment: Yeah you will have to scale and position any objects you want to be affected. If you just target the exportRoot, it will only scale the exportRoot. My recommendation is to put all children in a Container on the stage, and scale/position that.

Comment: Now I have a new problem. Resizing with a active tween will screw it up.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/ecr7o551/1/

Basically you just store the original canvas size and then use that to work out new positions and sizes

html

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400">
    Canvas was unable to start up.
</canvas>

<button onclick="resize()">Click me</button>
```

javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var originalWidth = canvas.width;
var originalHeight = canvas.height;

render = function()
{
    context.fillStyle = "#DDD";
    context.fillRect(0,0, originalWidth * (canvas.width / originalWidth), originalHeight * (canvas.height / originalHeight));

    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    var fontSize = 48 * (canvas.width / originalWidth);
    context.font = fontSize+"px serif";
    context.fillText("Hello world", 100 * (canvas.width / originalWidth), 200 * (canvas.height / originalHeight));   
}

resize = function()
{
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 600;
    render();
}

render();
```

Comment: I'm gonna use your answer as the solution. It will be very complex to implement in my situation but I think its the only option I have.

Comment: Yea if you have to implement it in the middle of a build or at the end it can cause some problems, however now you know and knowing is half the battle :)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 canvas element works with two different sizes

- Visual size on screen, controlled via CSS, like you're setting with canvas.style.width/height
- Size of pixel buffer for the drawing, controlled via numeric width and height pixel attributes on the canvas element.

The browser will stretch the buffer to fit the size on screen, so if the two values are not 1:1 ratio text will look blurry.

Try adding the following lines to your code

```
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
```

Comment: but then the text doesn't scale with the canvas.

Comment: Can you post self contained example, jsfiddle etc. so I can have a better look...

Comment: It think it won't work in Jsfiddle because I'm using Adobe Flash to build the HTML5 file and it uses the createJS and movieclip libraries. But the whole code is here: http://pastebin.com/xbYUi3ew

Answer (score 0):

I created a function to resize all the elements on the screen after resizing the canvas. It saves the initial coordinates and scales for the elements with the original width of 900 px and then it changes them according to the current width ratio relative to the original width ratio. The text isn't blurry/bad quality anymore.

```
    resize = function() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            var canvasRatio = canvas.height / canvas.width;

            var windowRatio = window.innerHeight / window.innerWidth;
            var width;
            var height;

            if (windowRatio < canvasRatio) {
                height = window.innerHeight;
                width = height / canvasRatio;
            } else {
                width = window.innerWidth;
                height = width * canvasRatio;
            }

            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            reziseElements();

        };


    reziseElements = function()
            {
                var canvrat = canvas.width / 900;

                 //Simplified
                stage.scaleX = stage.scaleY = canvrat;

                //Old Version
                /*for (i=0; i<stage.numChildren ;i++)
                {
                    currentChild = stage.getChildAt(i);

                    if (typeof currentChild.oscaleX == 'undefined')
                    {
                        currentChild.oscaleX = currentChild.scaleX;
                        currentChild.ox = currentChild.x;
                        currentChild.oy = currentChild.y;
                    }
                }   


                for (i=0; i<stage.numChildren ;i++)
                {
                    currentChild = stage.getChildAt(i);
                    currentChild.scaleX = currentChild.scaleY = currentChild.oscaleX * canvrat      
                    currentChild.x = currentChild.ox * canvrat
                    currentChild.y = currentChild.oy * canvrat
                }   */
            }
```

Comment: Rather than scale all your elements, put them into a container, and scale that. If you are using the Flash CC export, you should be able to just target the `exportRoot` that it creates.